# Is there any Disk Cache solution for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, caching

My client has a busy traffic site with a big amount of pages, ASP.NET's built-in cache solutions is good, but it only stores content into the memory. Since the site has a big amount of pages, so I think disk caching would be a better idea. But after searching I didn't find a solution, any suggestions?

Comment: ASP.NET dynamic page caching is not always a good idea. Is the content static?

Comment: @Kangkan: Why do you say that?

Comment: If the content is dynamic and the content to be delivered in every request differs from each other, then there is no point of caching the same. The caching is good when there is a processing time involved and the output does remain same.

Comment: That's why there's the 'VaryByParam' option.  A version of the page is cached for each value of the parameter.  ASP.Net caching is very flexible.  The downside is that it can be memory intensive for large sites as 'silent' is running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET 4.0 allows you to write your own cache provider. [Scott Gu's blog discusses the details.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There is the [ConcurrentCache project on codeplex](http://concurrentcache.codeplex.com/) which has support for 4 caching modes:

- Memory
- Files
- Compressed
- Auto

I can't say much about the project as I only just found it myself but I'm giving it a go right now.

Comment: FWIW I haven't had very good success so far with this, I'm not sure if this is ready for production usage.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4 lets you write your own using [OutputCacheProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.outputcacheprovider.aspx) and there may be some examples out there.  No doubt someone will roll out an open source project around this when .Net 4 gets more traction.

There was one in ASP.Net 2.0 Betas apparently, but it got removed in the RTM.  You can still find references to the web.config *DiskCache* parameter.

Comment: Has any project emerged as a de facto standard as far as anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/maxtoroq/4540845) is based on Scott Mitchell's article.

Answer (score 0):

[DiskCache.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DiskCache.NET) is a library that lets you cache data in a file.